# How to reference this property of a class?

Tags: php

I have the following class:

```
stdClass Object
(
   [@attributes] => Array
   (
      [bla] => 1122
    )
   [element] => Array
   (
      [bla] => 1122
    )
)
```

I want to reference the @attributes part of the class. It's easy enough to do it for the "element" one... that would be:

```
$class->element['bla']
```

But the same isn't true for the attribute one. The following doesn't work:

```
$class->@attributes['bla']
$class->"@attributes"['bla']
$class->(@attributes)['bla']
```

How do I call that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do

```
echo $class->{'@attributes'}['bla'];
//or
$name = '@attributes';
echo $class->$name['bla'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$varname = '@attributes';
print_r($object->$varname);
```